# What is the latest development of EOS.IO Storage?

Tags: storage, resources, bancor

Does anyone know the latest development of EOS.IO Storage?
This includes the determination of storage supply and the status of implementing IPFS.

I found this article from BM, yet it was a year ago.
https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/EOS.IO%20Storage.pdf

Under storage supply, it mentions a CRR of 10 used in Bancor algorithm, but it seems Connector weight replaces CRR under Bancor whitepaper
https://storage.googleapis.com/website-bancor/2018/04/01ba8253-bancor_protocol_whitepaper_en.pdf

Appreciate your response, thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem B1 is focusing on IPFS storage right now. However, anyone could in principle develop a dapp for that purpose. I predict that if something like EOS.IO Storage is ever implemented in EOS mainnet, the servers hosting the files won't necessarily be the BPs, but other actors separately elected through the dapp, with its own token. One reason for this is division of labour. The dynamics of BPs (with stand bys) probably won't be the best regarding IPFS storage. This will need its own careful design.